# Apply multiple filters from multiple comboboxes

Tags: delphi, filter, combobox, pascal, tadotable

I have an adotable and i want to apply multiple filter from multiple coboboxes, each combobox applies a filter to that table. My problem is whenever i choose an item from combobox1 for example it applies its filter but when i choose another item from the next combobox which is combobox2 it deletes the previous filter(combobox1) and applies the filter from combobox2. My question is: how can i make the adotable keep the previous filters from combobox1 or combobox2 or even both but also adds the 3rd filter from combobox3 for more in-depth sorting? Thanks in advance.
This is what i got to so far:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOTable1.Filtered:=false;
ADOTable1.filter:='`enter code here`field1='+ QuotedStr(ComboBox1.Text);
ADOTable1.Filtered:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOTable1.Filtered:=false;
ADOTable1.filter:=adotable1.Filter+'and field2='+ QuotedStr(ComboBox1.Text);
ADOTable1.Filtered:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox3Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOTable1.Filtered:=false;
ADOTable1.filter:=adotable1.Filter+'and field3='+ QuotedStr(ComboBox1.Text);
ADOTable1.Filtered:=true;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

above code is error when you changed many times,so you need to re-combin the filter text every times

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ComboBoxChange();
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ComboBoxChange();
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox3Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ComboBoxChange();
end;


procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChange();
var
    count: integer;
    sFilter: string;
begin
    count := 0;
    sFilter := '`enter code here`';
    
    if(ComboBox1.Text <> '') then
    begin
        sFilter := 'field1=' + ComboBox1.Text;
        Inc(count);
    end;
    if(ComboBox2.Text <> '')then
    begin
        if count > 0 then
            sFilter := sFilter + 'and field2=' + ComboBox2.Text
        else
            sFilter := sFilter + ' field2=' + ComboBox2.Text
        Inc(count);
    end;
    if(ComboBox3.Text <> '')then
    begin
        if count > 0 then
            sFilter := sFilter + 'and field3=' + ComboBox3.Text
        else
            sFilter := sFilter + ' field3=' + ComboBox3.Text
        Inc(count);
    end;
    ADOTable1.Filtered:=false;
        ADOTable1.filter:=sFilter;
    ADOTable1.Filtered:=true;
end;
```

Comment: You can declare your `ComboBoxChange()` to match signature of `OnChange` event and set it to each ComboBox in "Event" tab in Object Inspector to not create 3 separate event handler which just call single function. Also it'll be good to initialize value of `sFilter` as empty string to not create any filters and skip further filtering in case if no ComboBox filled.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** Solution in this answer requires support of *Generics* so it won't work in old versions of Delphi <s>*(and you shouldn't)*</s>.

1. You can apply [`Tag`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Tag) property to store index of field which you'll use to get field name in filter generation.
   [image: Tag settings]
2. To store value of each filter you can use private [`TDictionary`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/Generics_Collections_TDictionary_(Delphi)) field of your *Form*.

   ```pascal
   uses 
     { here all other modules }, System.Generics.Collections;

   type
     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       { here all components declaration }
     strict private
       Filters: TDictionary<Integer, string>;
   ```

   We should initialize `Filters` on the App start. You can do it in any place where you perform your initial setup (`OnCreate`, `OnShow` or any other event of Form; `initialization` section; etc.). I'll use [`OnCreate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnCreate) event handler just as example. You can generate empty handler and attach it to Form automatically in *Event* tab of *Object Inspector* by double clicking on empty cell near OnCreate:
   [image: OnCreate event handler]

   So now we should initialize `Filters` in this event handler:

   ```pascal
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     { here all your previous setup (if exist) }
     Filters := TDictionary<Integer, string>.Create;
   end;
   ```

   Also there you should initialize default values of your filters if you need them. It's necessary to do this if you set default values of `Text` in *Object Inspector* and want them to be used in filter query, because such as values won't be saved automatically into our `Filters` as none of `OnChange` events triggered.
3. Now let's define universal [`OnChange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnCreate) event handler for `TComboBox` which will store value into `Filters`:

   Firstly we should add signature of our event handler to *public* section of *Form* class. Since public is the default access modifier in classes, you can add your function right under component listing or another handlers *(if exist)*:

   ```pascal
   type
     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       { here all components declaration }
       procedure ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
   ```

   Then you can just point cursor on this declaration and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> which should let IDE generate empty function like this:

   ```pascal
   procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
   begin

   end;
   ```

   We've already defined unique `Tag` value for each ComboBox, so we could use it as a key. Event handler is pretty simple:

   ```pascal
   procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     with Sender as TComboBox do
       Filters.AddOrSetValue(Tag, Text);
   end;
   ```

   Finally you should add this event handler to each ComboBox. Copy name of function and paste it into an empty cell near `OnChange` in *Events* tab of *Object Inspector*, repeat this for each ComboBox you want to use for filtering:
   [image: OnChange event handler]
4. Final step is to write function which will generate filter query and update our event handler to work with ADOTable. Let's define our function in private section of Form class:

   ```pascal
   type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
     { here all components declaration }
   strict private
     Filters: TDictionary<Integer, string>;
     function GetFilterQuery(SkipEmptyValues: Boolean = False): string;
   ```

   Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to generate function. In function we will iterate over `Filters` using [`for ... in`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_Statements) loop, use [`string.Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Format) to create filter string for each element of `Filters` and [`string.Join`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Join) to join all created strings *(I've used [`TList<string>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList) as temporary data container)*:

   ```pascal
   function TForm1.GetFilterQuery(SkipEmptyValues: Boolean): string;
   var
     Pair: TPair<Integer, string>;
     Conditions: TList<string>;
   begin
     result := string.Empty;
     Conditions := TList<string>.Create;

     for Pair in Filters do
       with Pair do
         if (not SkipEmptyValues) or (not Value.IsEmpty) then
           Conditions.Add(string.Format('field%d=%s', [Key, Value.QuotedString]));

     if Conditions.Count > 0 then
       result := string.Join(' and ', Conditions.ToArray);

     Conditions.Free;
   end;
   ```

   At last, we should call this function in our `OnChange` event handler:

   ```pascal
   procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Query: string;
   begin
     with Sender as TComboBox do
       Filters.AddOrSetValue(Tag, Text);

     Query := GetFilterQuery(True);
     if not Query.IsEmpty then
     begin
       ADOTable1.Filtered := False;
       ADOTable1.Filter := Query;
       ADOTable1.Filtered := True;
     end;
   end;
   ```